# Java: ExecutorService less efficient than manual Thread executions?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I've got a multi-threaded application. When using Thread.start() to manually start threads every concurrent thread uses exactly 25% CPU (or exactly one core - this is on a quad core machine). So if I run two threads CPU usage is exactly 50%.

When using ExecutorService to run threads however, there seems to be one "ghost" thread consuming CPU resources! One Thread uses 50% instead of 25%, two thread use 75%, etc.

Could this be some kind of windows task manager artefact?

Excutor service code is

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadAmount);

for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new ActualThread(i);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

and Thread.start() code is:

```
ActualThread one= new ActualThread(2,3);
ActualThread two= new ActualThread(3,4);
...

Thread threadOne = new Thread(one);
Thread threadTtwo = new Thread(two);
...

threadOne.start();
threadTwo.start();
...
```

Comment: Where is the code to wait for the threads to finish in the second example?

Answer (score 16):

Here's your problem:

```
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
```

Your "main" method is spinning the CPU doing nothing.  Use [`invokeAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) instead, and your thread will block without a busy wait.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadAmount);
final List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();

for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    tasks.add(Executors.callable(new ActualThread(i)));
}
executor.invokeAll(tasks);
executor.shutdown();  // not really necessary if the executor goes out of scope.
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Since `invokeAll()` wants a collection of `Callable`, note the use of the helper method [`Executors.callable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#callable%28java.lang.Runnable%29).  You can actually use this to get a collection of `Future`s for the tasks as well, which is useful if the tasks are actually producing something you want as output.

Comment: +1, a slightly smaller change would be to use `awaitTermination`.

Comment: @Mark, yes, but why do the manual acrobatics when `invokeAll()` is there for you?  This model encourages reuse of the executor, too, which is often a good thing...  in any case, either works.